Angular 17 Control Flow @For without array of items
I use Angular 17,
Documentation says that i can iterate an array with control flow:
   @for (item of items; track $index)
     {
                    
     }

But I need to do something else like:
 @for (1 to 10; track $index)
 {
                
 }

Is It possible?
Solution o some suggestions

The @for block only accepts something iterable.
Your best alternative here is to create the array yourself :
 @for (i of [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; track $index)
 {
                
 }

Or create the array in your component with Array.from({length: 10}).
